# Checkbox addition in a dojo tree

Tags: jstl, dojo, dijit.tree

I want to implement check-boxes for my dojo tree. Checkbox option should be present against all folders of the tree hierarchy structure.

Can someone suggest how can I achieve this for my below tree?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to place checkboxes in a tree?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19614290/how-to-place-checkboxes-in-a-tree)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [plugin](http://www.thejekels.com/dojo/cbtree_AMD.html). Haven't tested it myself though.

Comment: one small query here which plugin do I need to use? It redirects me to a page with check box examples so is there any specific plugin i need to use here in my project and try?

Comment: I tried to use below script to get checkboxes but it is not showing checkbox but it is printing a string for all nodes of my tree. Am I doing something incorrect here. Please suggest if we can do this way to show up the check-box for folders in the tree structure. some codes will be helpful since i am implementing this for first time.Here is what I did: var tree = new Tree({model: model,checkBoxes: true,persist: false,getLabel: function(item) {if (!item.root)return '<input type="checkbox" name="'+ item.name +'" id="'+ item.name +'" value="1" /> '+ item.name;
 } }, "tree"); 
tree.startup();
});

Comment: They have a [code sample](http://www.thejekels.com/dojo/cbtree_AMD.html#sample). I've never used this myself so I can't be of much help.

Comment: Worked!!many thanks for the reply, I created the checkbox tree finally :) am very very happy thanks again..Is there a way I can vote your answer with maximum points please tell me as I am new to this forum so I dont know what are the options to vote for correct reply